# border and outline overlapping in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

On focus i am adding an outline to a button but the outline is overlapping with the border in Internet Explorer.This is working fine in Chrome.

Code:

```
 <div id="right" role="button" tabindex="0">
    <div class="rightcontent">
        test 
     </div>
 </div> 

#right {
height:39px;
dispaly:inline;
width:46px;
}

.rightcontent {
padding: 10px;
width:26px;
height:18px;
border-bottom :1px solid #000;
position:relative;
}
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/yhmcLgus/5/

Is this an Internet Explorer bug? Shouldn't outline be outside of elements dimensions?

Please suggest what can be done without changing the height of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`outline-offset` is one of the methods to set outline outside of an element. But it is not supported well in Internet Explorer. But by using an alternative solution of `pseudoelement` you can achieve the desired result.

```
<div id="right" role="button" tabindex="0">
  <div class="rightcontent">
    test 
  </div>
</div> 

#right {
 height:39px;
 dispaly:inline;
 width:46px;
}

.rightcontent {
  padding: 10px;
  width:26px;
  height:18px;
  border-bottom :1px solid #000;
  position:relative;
}

.rightcontent::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 46px;
  height: 41px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Here is the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yhmcLgus/5/)